# System.OutOfMemory exception when calling MemoryStream.ToArray() after serializing object with DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractserializer, memorystream

I am getting an intermittent "out of memory" exception at this statement:

```
        return ms.ToArray();
```

In this method:

```
public static byte[] Serialize(Object inst)
{
    Type t = inst.GetType();
    DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(t);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    dcs.WriteObject(ms, inst);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

How can I prevent it?  Is there a better way to do this?

The length of ms is 182,870,206 bytes (174.4 MB)

I am putting this into a byte array so that I can then run it through compression and store it to disk.  The data is (obviously) a large list of a custom class that I am downloading from a WCF server when my silverlight application starts.  I am serializing it and compressing it so it uses only about 6MB in isolated storage.  The next time the user visits and runs the silverlight application from the web, I check the timestamp, and if good I just open the file from isolated, decompress it, deserialize it, and load my structure.  I am keeping the entire structure in memory because the application is mostly geared around manipulating the contents of this structure.

@configurator is correct.  The size of the array was too big.  I rolled by own serializer, by declaring a byte array of [list record count * byte count per record], then stuffed it directly myself using statements like this to stuff it:

```
    Buffer.BlockCopy(
           BitConverter.GetBytes(node.myInt),0,destinationArray,offset,sizeof(int)); 
    offset += sizeof(int);
```

and this to get it back:

```
    newNode.myInt= BitConverter.ToInt32(sourceByteArray,offset); 
    offset += sizeof(int);
```

Then I compressed it and stored it to isolated storage.

My size went from 174MB with the DataContractSerializer to 14MB with mine.
After compression it went from a 6MB to a 1MB file in isolated storage.

Thanks to Configurator and Filip for their help.

Comment: How big is your object? This should only happen if your serialized data has a very large size. Or perhaps if you serialize many medium(100k or so) sized objects.

Comment: Are you expecting the serialized contract to be big?  If so and you are going to do IO with the resulting bytes, you might try using a FileStream etc. directly--

Comment: @code Edited post to show stream is 174.4 MB

Comment: You can chain streams together -- if you're using the compression APIs they're all stream based anyway, why do you need the data as an array of bytes at all?  Just serialize the data directly into a compression stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're expecting to return a 180MB byte array. That means the framework would need to find and allocate a consecutive 180MB of free memory to copy the stream data into, which is usually quite hard - hence the OutOfMemoryException. If you need to continue handling this amount of memory, use the memory stream itself (reading and writing to it as you need) to hold the buffer; otherwise, save it to a file (or to whatever other place you need it, e.g. serving it over a network) directly instead of using the memory stream.

I should mention that the memory stream has a 180MB array of its own in there as well, so is also in a bit of trouble and could cause OutOfMemory during serialization - it would likely be better (as in, more robust) if you could serialize it to a [temporary file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx). You might also want to consider a more compact - but possibly less readable - serialization format, like json, binary serialization, or protocol buffers.

---

In response to the comment: to serialize directly to disk, use a `FileStream` instead of a `MemoryStream`:

```
public static void Serialize(Object inst, string filename)
{
    Type t = inst.GetType();
    DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(t);
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(filename)) {
        dcs.WriteObject(ms, inst);
    }
}
```

Comment: Really, I would think that `MemoryStream.ToArray()` would return the internal array that contained the stream data.

Comment: @John: It returns a copy of it. First, it needs to be trimmed down to the memory stream's length; second, otherwise modifications to it or the memory stream would overlap - but only sometimes.

Comment: @configurator  Could you outline an approach (or even code) that would let me serialize and compress this object directly to disk.   I don't care if it's readable, nobody is going to look at it.  I just want to save it in a small space on disk and load it directly in to memory next time they load up the app.

Comment: @Brad: "I don't care if it's readable, nobody is going to look at it" - you should **always** care if it's readable; if they code isn't readable you can never be sure if it's correct! I've updated the answer with the changes you need to make to save it to file.

Comment: @configurator: I didn't mean the code, I meant the serialized/compressed file :)

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot more sense, sorry. If you're writing to file and you want to use a binary serializer, have a look at [System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx).

Comment: @configurator: Thanks for the code. How would I throw some compression in there? That's going to result in a file 170MB, right?  Is that a lot of space to take up on web user's drives?  You mentioned some other more compact serialization?

Comment: I've never used it, but [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) is a much more efficient serialization format.

Comment: I'd go with Json.net as first attempt. Its use of string property names makes it simpler to use that protobuf. And then put the output through a compression stream dotnetzip. If you really need the lower space protobuf will be better, but it typically requires a bit more configuration, like giving properties integer IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you use that code, but one thing that strikes me is that you don't release your resources. For instance, if you call `Serialize(obj)` a lot of times with a lot of large objects, you will end up having a lot of memory being used that is not released directly, however the `GC` should handle that properly, but you should always release your resources.

I've tried this piece of code:

```
public static byte[] Serialize(object obj)
{
    Type type = obj.GetType();
    DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(type);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        dcs.WriteObject(stream, obj);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

With the following `Main`-method in a Console Application

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var filipEkberg = new Person {Age = 24, Name = @"Filip Ekberg"};

    var obj = Serialize(filipEkberg);
}
```

However, my `byte`-array is not nearly as big as yours. [Having a look at this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796719/c-compact-framework-outofmemoryexception-with-xmlserializer-serialize), you might want to consider checking out [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

It might also be interesting to know what you are intending to do with the serialized data, do you need it as a `byte`-array or could it just as well be XML written to a text-file?

Comment: @Brad, as @configurator said and as the link I provided also says, it's a limitation and @configurator explains sort of why it's like that. You will need to look into alternatives like serializing to disk instead of memory. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I've been testing with your approach Filip, and it cleared up the write, but then I'm still getting outOfMemory on the read (even with a using statement). So this approach won't work for me, although I agree that it is better to wrap in a using that to not have one. @configurator 's approach won't work for me either, because I can't put a 174 M file on my user's drive, and his approach doesn't compress.  I hesitant to use protobuf-net as I am concerned about adding an external dependency that may not migrate well as new silverlight versions are released.

Comment: @Brad, I am tempted to reproduce the problem, can you tell me a little bit about the system specs on the machine that gets `OutOfMemoryException` ? Maybe using external dependencies is the only way, you can always deploy it within your binary if the licens allowes that.

Comment: it's my co-worker that is having the problem running this - I can't repeat it on my machine.  If I'm still stuck by Monday I'll see if I can get his specs.  Right now I'm converting the structure manually and stuffing it directly into a 14.6 Mbyte byte array.  Then I'll compress it and write to isolated storage.  I think it might work.

Answer (score -1):

Try to serialize to a stream (i.e. FileStream) instead of byte array. This way you can serialize gigabytes of data without OutOfMemory exception.

```
        public static void Serialize<T>(T obj, string path)
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(path);
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(string path)
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            Stream stream = File.OpenRead(path);
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }
```

Answer (score -4):

Try to set memory stream position to 0 and after only call ToArray().

Regards.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, infact i wrote "try" don't have pc on my hands to try it out.

Comment: @Tigran that is why that should have been a comment Mr.Tigran